# filesystem scm load stuck in jenkinfile-runner

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run jenkinsfile via the jenkinsdile-runner.

My jenkinsfile contains load shared library via filesystem scm plugin.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Load Library') {
            steps {
                library identifier: 'my@TestCase', 
                        retriever: legacySCM(
                        filesystem(clearWorkspace: false, copyHidden: false, path: "/workspace/my"))
                }
            }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                    my_method_to_run a: "aaaa"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Via execution the load shared lib is stuck.

```
Loading library my@TestCase
FSSCM.checkout /workspace/my_shared_library to /tmp/jenkinsfileRunner.tmp/jfr5221246900865917223.run/workspace/job@libs/my
```

I can't find any errors.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I forget to mention that it's not working when I run jenkinsfile-runner as docker. If I use the CLI the same pipe is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [jira ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56846)

I found WA.

Before I call the library command I manually create the /tmp/jenkinsfileRunner.tmp/jfr408537468992298463.run/workspace/job@libs folder and copy files to there.

After it my jenkinsfile run successfully via docker.

```
 stage('Load Library') {
                    steps {
                        sh "echo 'WA - when running via docker the load library stuck, do the preparation manually'"
                        sh "mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}/../job@libs/"
                        sh "rm -rf /workspace/my_shared_library/.git"
                        sh "cp -r /workspace/my_shared_library ${WORKSPACE}/../job@libs"

                        library identifier: 'my_shared_library@main', 
                                retriever: legacySCM(
                                filesystem(clearWorkspace: false, copyHidden: false, path: '/workspace/my_shared_library'))
                    }
                }
```